# Conditional filtering in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JSON file ...

```
[{
    "Event_code": "AB-001",
    "Interest_area": "Arts and Education",
    "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
    "End_time": "3:00 PM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-002",
    "Interest_area": "Arts and Education",
    "Start_time": "12:30 PM",
    "End_time": "1:00 PM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-003",
    "Interest_area": "",
    "Start_time": "9:00 AM",
    "End_time": "3:00 PM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-004",
    "Interest_area": "Business",
    "Start_time": "10:30 AM",
    "End_time": "11:00 AM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-005",
    "Interest_area": "General Interest",
    "Start_time": "9:30 AM",
    "End_time": "1:30 PM",
    "Session_type": "Experience"
}, {
    "Event_code": "AB-006",
    "Interest_area": "Environment ,    Business       ",
    "Start_time": "11:00 AM",
    "End_time": "11:30 AM",
    "Session_type": "Course information session"
}]
```

I want to filter this JSON where "*Session_type*" is equal to "*Course information session*" and "*Interest_area*" is equal to "*Business*"

What I have tried so far ....

```
let search = 'Course information session';
let result = [...new Set(arr.filter(o=>o.Session_type === search && o.Interest_area.trim() !== '' && o.Interest_area === "Business"))]
console.log(result);
```

**This code only returns event with Event_code 'AB-004' and NOT 'AB-006'** I want to return both AB-004 and AB-006

Can someone please advise what am I doing wrong ? Thanks

Comment: try `o.Interest_area.includes("Business")`

Comment: Why are you using a `Set`? I think you need to revise your requirement of _"'Interest_area' is equal to 'Business'"_ since `AB-006` does not meet it

Comment: `o.Interest_area === "Business"` mean the whole text value is "Business", use `.contains('Business')` instead

Comment: @Phil Creating a `Set` out of an array and then spreading it back into another array is a quick and dirty way of returning an array of only unique values.

Comment: @Andrew but none of the objects in this array are duplicated. It's impossible for a JSON array to contain duplicates unless the entries are primitives

Comment: @Phil I think the code OP posted is just a part of the entire code. I remember answering the (original) question few days ago. OP wants to have unique `Interest_area` as a final result.

Comment: That's fine for strings but the `Set` in this code is doing nothing.

Comment: Yeah.. OP wants a simple array and not a multi dimensional array as final result on the original post. I think he just copied the code or something.

Comment: Thanks Eddie, @Dean, Andrew, Phil.  BTW what is the difference between "contains" and "includes". Which method is more efficient ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string#includes` instead of `===` equality comparison, since you want to determines whether one string may be found within another string.

```js
let arr = [{ "Event_code": "AB-001", "Interest_area": "Arts and Education", "Start_time": "9:00 AM", "End_time": "3:00 PM", "Session_type": "Course information session" }, { "Event_code": "AB-002", "Interest_area": "Arts and Education", "Start_time": "12:30 PM","End_time": "1:00 PM", "Session_type": "Course information session" }, { "Event_code": "AB-003", "Interest_area": "", "Start_time": "9:00 AM", "End_time": "3:00 PM", "Session_type": "Course information session" }, { "Event_code": "AB-004", "Interest_area":"Business", "Start_time": "10:30 AM", "End_time": "11:00 AM", "Session_type": "Course information session" }, { "Event_code": "AB-005", "Interest_area": "General Interest", "Start_time": "9:30 AM", "End_time": "1:30 PM", "Session_type": "Experience" },{ "Event_code": "AB-006", "Interest_area": "Environment , Business ", "Start_time": "11:00 AM", "End_time": "11:30 AM", "Session_type": "Course information session" }],
    search = 'Course information session',
    result = arr.filter(o => o.Session_type === search && o.Interest_area.trim() !== '' && o.Interest_area.includes("Business"));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Using `String.prototype.includes` may result in false positives (like "Businesses"). A somewhat better option might be `/\bBusiness\b/.test(o.Interest_area)`

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
let arr = [{ "Event_code": "AB-001", "Interest_area": "Arts and Education", "Start_time": "9:00 AM", "End_time": "3:00 PM", "Session_type": "Course information session" }, { "Event_code": "AB-002", "Interest_area": "Arts and Education", "Start_time": "12:30 PM","End_time": "1:00 PM", "Session_type": "Course information session" }, { "Event_code": "AB-003", "Interest_area": "", "Start_time": "9:00 AM", "End_time": "3:00 PM", "Session_type": "Course information session" }, { "Event_code": "AB-004", "Interest_area":"Business", "Start_time": "10:30 AM", "End_time": "11:00 AM", "Session_type": "Course information session" }, { "Event_code": "AB-005", "Interest_area": "General Interest", "Start_time": "9:30 AM", "End_time": "1:30 PM", "Session_type": "Experience" },{ "Event_code": "AB-006", "Interest_area": "Environment , Business ", "Start_time": "11:00 AM", "End_time": "11:30 AM", "Session_type": "Course information session" }];

let search = 'Course information session', interestArea = "Business";
let result = arr.filter(o=> o.Session_type === search && o.Interest_area.includes(interestArea));

console.log(result);
```

**Note**: Use **Set** only if you want to remove duplicates, however, there are no duplicates in the array, hence, you can avoid using it.

Comment: Thanks @NikhilAggarwal for explaining "Set" usage. That was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Interest_area at **AB-006** :

```
    "Interest_area": "Environment ,    Business       ",
```

Interest_area === "Business" will always be false. Try this :

```
Interest_area.includes("Business")
```

Will return true.

Comment: Thanks @FacundoBringas, you are spot on. That explanation was really helpful.